# codeigniter What are the libraries available for payment methods?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, payment

I am working on a social networking site. I have to develop payment module in it. It has one subscribe button. User can subscribe our additional features by making payment. After clicking on subscribe button it will ask for user debit/credit card,card number, expiry etc.

I can do it? where i can get help on it? Recommend me any API/Library
I m working on Code-Igniter (PHP) framework.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is a project on Github called `PHP Payments` which can be easily integrated with codeigniter

Check this out 
https://github.com/broncha/codeigniter-payments and

https://github.com/broncha/PHP-Payments

Answer (score 0):

Try these

[Codeignitor Payment Module](https://bitbucket.org/triplethree/codeigniter-reactor-payment-module)

[Spark for Uniform Payments in CodeIgniter, based on PHP-Payments. Supports 12+ payment gateways.](https://github.com/calvinfroedge/codeigniter-payments)

[Basic Information: codeigniter-payments](http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-payments/versions/HEAD/show)